# WSO2 EMM 2.1.1 : Device not present in the dashboard analytics

Tags: wso2-iot

I am currently installing with WSO2 EMM

I managed to set it correctly for my domain name.

I managed to put several tablets and smartphones under Android in the management console EMM.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Wlq0.png

In the emm-analytics-dashboard console, I do not see any devices

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZiU4.png

I'm use the WSO2 2.1.1 version

Can you help me please.

Sorry for my english because i'm french... I use Google Translator

Thank for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup authorization configuration in portal/configs/designer.json

```
"authorization": {
        "activeMethod": "oauth",
        "methods": {
            "oauth": {
                "attributes": {
                    "idPServer": "https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token", (or https://<your_ip>:9443/oauth2/token)
                    "dynamicClientProperties": {
                        "callbackUrl": "https://localhost:9443/portal", (or https://<your_ip>:9443/portal)
                        "clientName": "portal",
                        "owner": "admin",
                        "applicationType": "JaggeryApp",
                        "grantType": "password refresh_token urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:saml2-bearer",
                        "saasApp": false,
                        "dynamicClientRegistrationEndPoint": "https://localhost:9443/dynamic-client-web/register/", (or https://<your_ip>:9443/dynamic-client-web/register/)
                        "tokenScope": "Production"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Surely, This will help you.

Comment: I have already done many tests on the design.json

In the console, when I connect to emm-analytics-dashboard, here's what I have in the log: 
WARN {net.sf.ehcache.pool.sizeof.SizeOf} -  The configured limit of 1,000 object references was reached while attempting to calculate the size of the object graph. This can be avoided by adding stop points with @IgnoreSizeOf annotations. Thank for your help

Comment: Ok, On the designer.json there is : "host": { "hostname": "", "port": "", "protocol": "" } }

I have to provide additional information about this information?